# New diagram type support in plantuml- For Autosar visualization

Tags: plantuml

I'd like to modify the plantuml github codebase to support AutoSAR based visualization of ports,interfaces,components with customized icons.

Is there any directions which can help me to understand the github codebase of plantuml quickly so that I can contribute to plantuml code base, any developers manual type of document to jumpstart the development. How to contribute effici

Comment: https://fossies.org/dox/plantuml-1.2023.7/plantuml.html found from https://forum.plantuml.net/11749/source-code-documentation?show=11749#q11749